# UserDefaults resetting with new launch

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a program which plays different audio clips when the user presses the play button. For an audio to be played the credit value has to be greater than 1. I have tried using UserDefaults as follows but it seems to be resetting every time.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,.....
    var dataCredit = 3

    ....

    @IBAction func playsound(_ sender: Any) {
        defaults.set(dataCredit, forKey: "credits")

        credit = defaults.integer(forKey: "credits")

        if credit > 0 {
            feedLabel.text = "you have credits)"
            dataCredit = dataCredit - 1
            defaults.set(dataCredit, forKey: "credits")
            dataCredit = defaults.integer(forKey: "credits")
        } else if credit == 0 {
            feedLabel.text = "you dont have Credit\(startCredit)"
        }
```

This is what I currently have. Every time I restart the app the dataCredit is back to 3 and it doesn't remember the value I stored.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you always call `defaults.set(dataCredit, forKey: "credits")` as the first thing in the action. You are doing it like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,.....

....


@IBAction func playsound(_ sender: Any) {
    if let credit = defaults.integer(forKey: "credits"), credit > 0 {
        feedLabel.text = "you have credits)"
        dataCredit = dataCredit - 1
        defaults.set(dataCredit, forKey: "credits")
        dataCredit = defaults.integer(forKey: "credits")
    } else if credit == 0 {
        feedLabel.text = "you dont have Credit\(startCredit)"
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**

To set an initial value for the credit, I'd suggest to do it in the AppDelegate - `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // ...

    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["credits" : 3])

    // ...

    return true
}
```

Comment: hi i tried this, it works but it doesnt give me a chance to set the start the credit at value 3

Comment: @Prez So do you want an initial value for it as 3?

Comment: yes and the value 3 wil be remembered, it can +1 and it can -1

Comment: The correct approach for initial/default values would be `UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["credits" : 3])`